# Public Int Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to create a menu that goes to different sections without using a class but I am receiving errors using public int.

```
 public int menu()
        Console.WriteLine("Select a category to view");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("1.Groceries");
        Console.WriteLine("2.Electronics & Appliances");
        Console.WriteLine("3.Exit");
        Console.ReadKey();

      int User = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (User)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("...........Groceries...............");
                break;

            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("..............Electronics &   Appliances............");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("...........Exit...............");
               break;
```

}

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What is the public int?

Comment: You simply can't have a method outside a class.

Comment: 'Program.menu()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial and Description Project File Line
'<invalid-global-code>.Parse(Console.ReadLine)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Comment: This looks like somebody who was doing Python before ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning your function into a static void method solves the problem. And you are missing the `{` after the `menu()`. Following your paradigm the code would be:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void menu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Select a category to view");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("1.Groceries");
            Console.WriteLine("2.Electronics & Appliances");
            Console.WriteLine("3.Exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
            int User = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (User)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("...........Groceries...............");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("..............Electronics &   Appliances............");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("...........Exit...............");
                    break;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            menu();
        }
    }
}
```